# When is it best to use false as second parameter of Response.Redirect and when not?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In general, for .NET everyone recommends to use:

```
Response.Redirect("url", false)
```

instead of

```
Response.Redirect("url", true)
```

to avoid race conditions as the latter apparently ends the process abruptly.

Is there any case where it makes sense to use `true` instead of `false`?

Is also `false` more suitable than `true` when the redirect is not a postback to the very same aspx page but a redirect to a different aspx page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At its simplest, you use `true` when you want to end the response and `false` when you don't.  (Note that `true` is the default if none is supplied in this case.)

For starters, ending the response in this manner will throw a `ThreadAbortException`, so in general I'd avoid it if possible.  That exact exception scenario has caught many ASP.NET developers by surprise in production environments over the years.  And it's not necessary to throw an exception when nothing exceptional is happening, just normal logic flow.

I'd say that best practice would be to structure the logic flow accordingly such that you can end the execution without having to abort the thread.  In *many* cases, a simple `return;` after the `Response.Redirect()` accomplishes that.  In more complex cases (that is, in cases where you end up with a lot of `return;` paths throughout large code-behind methods), chances are that the problem isn't with the redirect but rather with runaway method sizes that need to be refactored into something more manageable.

Just remember that `Response.Redirect()` is *not* a way to exit a method.  Forget the fact that you're performing a redirect for a moment, and consider that this is normal C# code where logic flow needs to exit the method accordingly.  If the `Response.Redirect()` is the last thing the method does, or the last thing that logic flow in general does, then you should be fine.

Comment: If the Response.Redirect("url",false) is executed in an inner method of an event handler, does the thread end when the inner method ends with return or does it end when whole event handler has been executed?

Comment: @Pep: Code execution would continue back up the stack if the redirect is multiple methods deep.  Aborting the thread would kill that stack, but at the cost of an exception.  So if `MethodA()` calls `MethodB()` and the latter does the redirect, when control returns to the former it will still execute.  Ideally the logic shouldn't *be* so complex as to make that an issue, though.  If it is, consider the redirect condition as something by which to exit the logic and structure the code accordingly.  That is, forget the redirect itself and focus on trying to "return" from `MethodB()` effectively.

Comment: Thanks, got it. However, one of the redirects occurs in Page_Init, which checks if Session variable is null (expired session) and if it is null, then redirects to the login page. In this case, I understand that "true" makes more sense to avoid that other events such as Page_Load continue to execute after the redirect in Page_Init. Am I right with this assumption?

Comment: @Pep: Perhaps, and it's worth testing.  The page life cycle is separate from standard logic flow and may check for such conditions already.  (I can't say for certain, it's been a *long* time since I've done Web Forms work.)

Answer (score 1):

`false` will be used to not to abort the Thread so that the statements after/below the `Response.Redirect()` will be executed.

here client will be redirected to new page but still current page willbe Executed by the `Server`

`true` will be used to redirect by aborting the thread so statements after/below the `Response.Redirect()` will not be executed.

here client will be redirected to new page and  current page will notbe Executed by the `Server`

Answer (score 0):

On thing for sure, you want to use `Response.Redirect("url", false)` if it is in `try catch` block.

Otherwise, it will throw ThreadAbortException.

```
try {
  Response.Redirect("url", false);
}
catch(Exception ex) {
   // Log exception
}
```