# Response.Redirect("Sign up.aspx",false);

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Is it necessary to put second parameter false.. If yes then why? if not then why not?

I have read it from google but i am not able to understand...Any precise reply will be appreciated

As we can use single parameter also

Comment: Probably your answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911262/when-is-it-best-to-use-false-as-second-parameter-of-response-redirect-and-when-n

Answer (score 5):

you can use just one parameter as URL or using `true` as second parameter but this make `System.Threading.ThreadAbortException` in some cases. `Response.Redirect(string URL,true)` make `response.End()` automatically and stop the page process.

When you use `false` as second parameter, you tell the compiler that don't stop the page processing even after page redirection and this create some other problem. To prevent this issues you can use `false` as second parameter and `return;` keyword just after `response.redirect`.